# Get a value from a echo json_encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I need to echo json_encode($return); in a model file using codeigniter

Also i need to get one value from this echoing in the controller file that call this model.

Is this possible ? how can it be done ?

Thank´s in advance

Comment: Please, provide your code

Comment: //model
echo(json_encode($return));

//controller
$id = $this->generic_controller->genericMethod($parameter_one,$parameter_two);

Comment: I need to get $id from the return echoed from the model in the controller

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo Code does little help in a comment.  Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo json_encode(array("name"=>"Test"));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Last I checked, that's not how `json_encode()` works.  It outputs a string, not an object.

Comment: Yes sorry that's suppose to be for json_decode. Edited.

Comment: Okay.  The OP already tried that, though.  At least in some semblance.  The correct answer would be to address how this is done in the framework they're using.